# Updated htmltools doesn't install anyway

Tags: r, namespaces, htmltools

In Rmarkdown my problem is

> Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
> namespace 'htmltools' 0.5.6 is already loaded, but >= 0.5.7 is required
> Calls:  ... is_bs_theme -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
> Execution halted

I tried all the process for update package. But my problem can't solve any way. Please solve my issue to how can update " htmltools " for 0.5.7

Comment: Do this: `detach("package:htmltools", unload=TRUE)` and install it again.

Comment: What does `.libPaths()` show?  What do you see when you run `install.packages("htmltools")`?  What kind of system are you running on?